# Set password aging for a group of users

Tags: password

With chage command we can change password expiry information for a user.
Is there anyway to enforce password aging for a group of users?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help.  You can set default password expiry using the file `/etc/login.defs`.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo nano /etc/login.defs
```

For example, you can setup values as shown below:

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30
PASS_MIN_DAYS 1
PASS_WARN_AGE 7
```

Once done, just close and save the file.

For more info see [login.defs manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html).

Comment: Nice. Did not know of this. Is it possible to apply to certain groups only?